# JQuery lightbox next image switch

Tags: jquery, lightbox

I am having an issue with switching to the next image in a lightbox.  When I click on the next button for the first time everything works ok.  I can't seem to get to the next image from there.  Below is the code I am using.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
      $('#portfolioGallery .pGallery').click(function(){    
        var firstImg = $(this).find('img').clone();
        var nextImg = $(this).next().find('img').clone();
        $('#lightbox').append(firstImg);
        $('#next').click(function(){                    
                $('#lightbox').find('img').remove();
                $('#lightbox').append(nextImg);

        })
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your code is probably working , but you keep cloning then selecting a clone of the same image , so it appears to not be wokring , I do not understand what the purpose of clone is in here

```
  $('#portfolioGallery .pGallery').click(function(){    
    var firstImg = $(this).find('img');
    var nextImg = $(firstImg).next().find('img');  //try this
    $('#lightbox').append(firstImg);
    $('#next').click(function(){                    
            $('#lightbox').find('img').remove();
            $('#lightbox').append(nextImg);
    })
```

Comment: I used clone to grab the image off the page but not remove it completely.  Is there a better method for this than clone?  Also, I have filters to hide certain images based on what button is clicked.  I'm trying to grab the next visible image to load into the lightbox.

Comment: Still no luck.  The problem without using clone(), gives me an empty div where my image used to be.  You did help me shorten my code though.  Thanks for that.

Comment: you can still try the clone, just make sure it is going .next after firstImg